# What is the best way to ignore all php requests coming for RoR project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

For example, there are such obviously unnecessary requests:

```
> tail -f log/production.log

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/wp-login.php"):
Started GET "/wp-login.php" for 95.96.26.49 at 2018-11-14 01:20:22 +0300
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/wp-login.php"):
Started GET "/wp-login.php" for 109.81.213.45 at 2018-11-14 01:28:27 +0300
```

And I want to disable this way for hack-requests, how can I do it?

Or may be other global way to prevent such?

Comment: They are already rejected by your app's router. Is that not enough?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well, then how is it better way to globally ignoring such php requests for minimally spent resources of server? I assume it is necessary must be in nginx?

Comment: Indeed, dropping them at nginx would be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To block in `nginx.conf`

```
location ~ \.php {
  return 404;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) gem as well for this, which can be handled a layer above than rails in rack.

```
  blocklist('block all urls ending with .php') do |req|
    req.path.match(/.php$/)
  end
```